# Create an image overlay on rollover in SP Page Builder

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I am trying to create a rollover effect as can be seen [here](https://www.mobas.com/expertise) but am struggling as to the best way to do it. The client has requested that the site be built using SP Page builder as they want to maintain and update it themselves which is causing some issues.

The block I am looking to have this effect on can be seen [here](https://precision.sitewidehosting.co.uk/) but I am struggling with the correct effects that will create this.  I have added a css class called rollbox to the first 'Data' box but the effect seems to be occurring underneath rather than on top.

```
/** Pod box effect on mouseover **/
.rollbox a{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.rollbox a>span{
    position:relative;
}

.rollbox::before{
    content:'';
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:0%;
    -webkit-transition:width .3s ease-out;
}
.rollbox:hover::before{
    width:100%;
}
```

Any pointers would be most appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I upgraded the page builder and created an Addon Override for the new Image Overlay addon. This then allowed me to do what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

For the current mark-up and with the CSS you have in place, add this extra CSS and you will get closer to the effect that you want.

```
.sppb-text-center {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rollbox:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    display: block;
}
```

---

> A few notes for this kind of questions:
>
> - This is not a Joomla question.
> - This is very specific and more like I need someone to do the work for me.